# GEKKO for minimum time solution optimal control problem

Tags: controls, gekko, optimal

This is a standard benchmark problem for minimum flight time.

[image: minimum time bencmark problem]

This is a very standard problem. I am trying to solve it in gekko, but it is neither converging to local minima nor global, here is the code. I followed the set up from the [Jennings problem](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/MinimizeFinalTime) but still, if anybody can help, that would be very nice.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
m = GEKKO()

nt = 501
tm = np.linspace(0,1,nt)
m.time = tm
x1=m.Var(value=-2.5)
x2=m.Var(value=0)
u=m.MV(value=1,lb=0,ub=2*math.pi)
p = np.zeros(nt)
p[-1] = 1.0
final = m.Param(value=p)
tf = m.FV(value=0,lb=0.1,ub=100.0)
tf.STATUS = 1
if x2.value>1:
   m.Equation(x1.dt()==((1+(x2-1)**2)*m.cos(u)*tf))
   m.Equation(x2.dt()==((1+(x2-1)**2)*m.sin(u)*tf))
else:
   m.Equation(x1.dt()==(m.cos(u)*tf))
   m.Equation(x2.dt()==(m.sin(u)*tf))

#m.Equation(x1*final<=3)
#m.Equation(x2*final<=0)
m.Minimize(tf)

m.options.IMODE = 6
m.solve()
tm = tm * tf.value[0]

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(tm,x1.value,'k-',lw=2,label=r'$x_1$')
plt.plot(tm,x2.value,'b-',lw=2,label=r'$x_2$')
plt.plot(tm,u.value,'r--',lw=2,label=r'$u$')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `m.if3()` function for the conditional statement. Here is the local solution that they discussed on pg 332 of the [Cristiani and Martinon publication](https://www.proquest.com/openview/cb898b48417e869e2d4d62377fa38a4a/1.pdf).

[image: Local solution]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
m = GEKKO()

nt = 101; pi = math.pi
tm = np.linspace(0,1,nt); m.time = tm
x1=m.Var(value=-2.5,lb=-100,ub=100)
x2=m.Var(value=0,lb=-100,ub=100)
u=m.MV(value=0,lb=-pi,ub=pi); u.STATUS=1; u.DCOST=0.1
p = np.zeros(nt); p[-1] = 1.0
final = m.Param(value=p)
tf = m.FV(value=10,lb=0.1,ub=100.0); tf.STATUS = 1
c = m.if3(x2-1,1,(x2-1)**2+1)
m.Equation(x1.dt()==c*m.cos(u)*tf)
m.Equation(x2.dt()==c*m.sin(u)*tf)

# hard constraints (fix endpoint)
#m.fix_final(x1,3)
#m.fix_final(x2,0)

# soft constraints (objective)
m.Minimize(100*final*(x1-3)**2)
m.Minimize(100*final*(x2-0)**2)

# minimize final time
# initialize with IPOPT Solver
m.Minimize(tf)
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.SOLVER=3
m.solve()

# find MINLP solution with APOPT Solver
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.options.TIME_SHIFT=0
m.solve()

tm = tm * tf.value[0]

plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
plt.plot(tm,x1.value,'k-',lw=2,label=r'$x_1$')
plt.plot(tm,x2.value,'b-',lw=2,label=r'$x_2$')
plt.plot(tm,u.value,'r--',lw=2,label=r'$u$')
plt.legend(loc='best'); plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Time'); plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.savefig('results.png',dpi=300); plt.show()
```

The global solution is shown in the paper.

[image: global solution]

The solvers in Gekko (APOPT, BPOPT, IPOPT) are local solvers. You need to add constraints or use different initial guess values to find the global optimum.